# Young women wear their hats poised fashionably low over their foreheads

Tags: grammar, meaning

> Young women wear their hats poised fashionably low over their foreheads.

What does the word poised mean in the above sentence?

Could someone please explain the grammatical structure of the sentence?

Comment: What did you find when you checked “poised” in your dictionary?

Comment: In the specified context, ***poised*** means ***positioned, placed***, with strong connotations of *[delicately / jauntily] **balanced, tilted, perched***. Either or both of [Merriam-Webster's definitions ...](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poised) *A: marked by balance or equilibrium, B: marked by easy composure of manner or bearing*.

Comment: ...Note that in this *exact* context, the *poise = balance, equilibrium* allusion attaches as much to the *wearer* as to the ***delicately** poised* (by implication, almost ***unstable***) hat itself - which is likely to be *[hat-]pinned* into the wearer's hair, so it won't fall off! :).

Comment: What words are you having trouble fitting into the grammar of the sentence?

Comment: “Poised” is the word I have trouble understanding its grammar function.

Comment: It's a verb participle describing the way the hat is placed on the head. Compare "He carried the ladder _balanced_ on his shoulder."

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense.